# Using google maps with require js async plugin does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, requirejs

The output of the console when I try and call `map.getZoom()` from `main.js`,the output of the console seems to suggest that the map has been loaded but is not being displayed:

```
 -34.397,150.644 maploader.js:19
 the map was loaded maploader.js:11
 The map is zoomed to 4 maploader.js:13
 From main main.js:22
 4
```

The map does not display when I try and display a map using `requirejs` modules like this:

## gmaps.js

```
  // return the gmaps namespace for brevity...

  define(['async!async!http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=API_KEY&sensor=true'],function(){
  return window.google.maps;
});
```

## maploader.js

```
 define(['gmaps'],function(gmaps){
    return{
        //args:DOM element(a div),LatLng(a point),minimum Zoom(set to 4)...
            fetchMap:function(what,cent,mZoom)
            {
                var mapOptions={center:cent,zoom:4,minZoom:mZoom};
                var map=new gmaps.Map(what,mapOptions);
                if(map===null || typeof map==='undefined')
                    console.log('The map was not loaded');
                else
                    console.log('the map was loaded');
                var z=map.getZoom();
                console.log("The map is zoomed to "+z);
                return map;
            },
            createLatLng:function(lat,lng)
            {
                var p=new gmaps.LatLng(lat,lng);
                console.log(p.lat()+','+p.lng());
            }
    }
});
```

## main.js

```
requirejs.config({
baseUrl:'scripts',
paths:{
    jquery:'lib/jquery.min',
    async:'lib/plugins/async',
    propertyParser:'lib/plugins/propertyParser',
    goog:'lib/plugins/goog'
}
});

require(['./maploader','jquery'],function(map,$){
   $(document).ready(function(){
     var myDiv=$("#map-canvas").get(0);
     var center=map.createLatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
     var myMap=map.fetchMap(myDiv,center,4);
     console.log('From main');
     console.log(''+map.getZoom());
  });
});
```

This is my directory structure:

```
~/Desktop/maps/modules_test $ ls -LR
.:
css  index.html  scripts

./css:
 init.css

./scripts:
 gmaps.js  lib  main.js  maploader.js

./scripts/lib:
 jquery.min.js  plugins  require.js

./scripts/lib/plugins:
 async.js   font.js  image.js  mdown.js  propertyParser.js
 depend.js  goog.js  json.js   noext.js
```

## UPDATE:

This does not work either,even worse it does not even print my console logs

```
require(['./gmaps','./maploader'],function(gmaps,map){
    var initialize=function()
    {
        var myDiv=document.getElementById('map-canvas');
        var center=map.createLatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var myMap=map.fetchMap(myDiv,center,4);
        console.log('From main');
        console.log(''+myMap.getZoom());
    };

    gmaps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `createLatLng()` doesn't return center value:

```
        createLatLng:function(lat,lng)
        {
            var p=new gmaps.LatLng(lat,lng);
            console.log(p.lat()+','+p.lng());
        }
```

There is no `return p;` statement.

Comment: You have no idea how far off the mark I was,I was  just examining the entire html of the document after require and gmaps had modified it for clues.Thank you